# Get repeating regex groups in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I'm working on a Scala app, and trying to parse a file using Regex.
The file format is something like this:

```
actions{
ACTION_NAME=[ELEMENT,ANOTHER_ELEMENT,SOMETHING_ELSE]
ANOTHER_ACTION=[SOMETHING_HERE,ANOTHER_ONE]
}
```

where the amount of elements within the curly brackets is dynamic.

I would like to iteratively match those rows to  tuples, (e.g.  ACTION_NAME | ELEMENT,ANOTHER_ELEMENT,SOMETHING_ELSE ) so
I matched it using the following Regex:

```
actions\{(?:[\s\n]*([A-Z_]+)=\[([A-Z_,]*)\][\s\n]*)*\}
```

The match works fine, but my matcher groups, include only the last key & value of course. How can I make the matcher to iterate over the repetitions and return all of the matches in the file as a key,value,key,value,key,value iterator...

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: `\s` means `[\r\n\t\f ]`. So, `[\s\n]` is redundant.

Comment: Try: `(\w+)\=\[([^\]]+)\]` 
Note: I have used `\w+` because I don't know about which type name of "ACTION_NAME" and "ANOTHER_ACTION".

Comment: I could suggest a `\G` based regex, but if you have several `ACTION=[S,A,E]`like substrings in one input, it will be hard to tell one from another. Use several step approach. Collect `ACTION=[...]`, then split by `=`, then split the second part with `,`.

Comment: Just to clarify, I succeed to match the entire pattern, the issue is just to iterate over all the matcher

Comment: @Yoav: No, it is not so. If you set a quantifier to a capturing group, only the last captured text is saved in its buffer.

Comment: Thanks, I used this method and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in one step. Scala does not support looking at match instances of a repeated group<sup>(*)</sup>.

Break it up:

- match `actions\{([^}]*)\}` against the entire input; for each match

  - take the contents of group 1
  - match `(\w+)=\[([^\]]*)\]` against it; for each match

    - the contents of group 1 will be the key
    - the contents of group 2 will be the list of items

      - split them at the comma to get individual items

---

<sup>(*)</sup> That's because Java doesn't support it. Other regex engines, most prominently the one in .NET, offer such a feature.

Answer (score 3):

Probably offtopic, but since post is tagged as `scala` I should warn, that generally parsing is not recommended to do via regular expressions.

Primarily because:

1. They need to handle each logical level separatedly
2. They do not allow recursive definitions at all
3. They allow very poor intermediate structure information
4. They become very frustrating from 3 or more lines of expression

So I allow myself to build small parser using super-efficient [`parboiled2` library](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#parboiled2-vs-regular-expressions)

```
import org.parboiled2._

import scala.util.Try

object Actions {
  case class Action(name: String, elems: Seq[String])

  def apply(input: String): Try[Seq[Action]] = new Actions(input).Input.run()
}

class Actions(val input: ParserInput) extends Parser {
  import Actions._

  def Input = rule {WS ~ "actions{" ~ WS ~ ActionList ~ WS ~ "}" ~ WS ~ EOI}

  def ActionList = rule {FirstAction ~ zeroOrMore(WS ~ ActionDef ~> ((_: Seq[Action]) :+ _))}

  def FirstAction = rule {ActionDef ~> (Vector(_))}

  def ActionDef = rule {(capture(Name) ~ "=[" ~ ElementList ~ "]") ~> Action.apply _}

  def ElementList = rule {
    WS ~ FirstElement ~ zeroOrMore(
      WS ~ "," ~ WS ~ NextElement ~> ((_: Seq[String]) :+ _))
  }

  def FirstElement = rule {capture(Name) ~> (Vector(_))}

  def NextElement = rule {capture(Name)}

  def Name = rule {oneOrMore(CharPredicate.Alpha | '_')}

  def WS = rule {zeroOrMore(anyOf(" \n\r\t\f"))}
}
```

From this point

```
Actions("""
   actions{
     ACTION_NAME=[ELEMENT,ANOTHER_ELEMENT,SOMETHING_ELSE]
     ANOTHER_ACTION=[SOMETHING_HERE,ANOTHER_ONE]
   }""")
```

results in

> Success(Vector(Action(ACTION_NAME,Vector(ELEMENT, ANOTHER_ELEMENT,
>   SOMETHING_ELSE)), Action(ANOTHER_ACTION,Vector(SOMETHING_HERE,
>   ANOTHER_ONE))))

while

```
Actions(
  """
   actions{
     ACTION_NAME=[ELEMENT,ANOTHER_ELEMENT,SOMETHING_ELSE]
     ANOTHER_ACTION=[SOMETHING_HERE,AN0THER_ONE]
   }""")
```

results in

```
Failure(ParseError(Position(109,4,39), ...
```

which specifically points you that first unexpected character was met at 36th character of 4th line, which is 109th character of whole input.

Comment: Very nice, definitely recommendable over any regex-based approach.